# WordPress: $wpdb->insert(); doesn’t escape data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Insert

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'table',
    array(
        'column' => '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Oops!");</script>',
    )
);
```

Result (DB)

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Oops!");</script>
```

Not

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Oops!\");</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such escaping is user-defined. You wouldn't want WordPress changing the contents of your queries.

Try using the [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) `prepare()` method and pass your argument through [`addslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)()

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows | “Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped).” | Why?

Comment: Probably because of architecturally built-in SQL injection protections. In my experience, you're supposed to use `prepare` to insert raw values. Even stuff like `LIKE` values with [`like_escape()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/like_escape)